# Traduction du terme informatique "agentless" en français

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, informatique

Bonjour, je traduis actuellement des pages webs d'une société de sauvegarde informatique et il est écrit à un moment:

> Your RPO: 10 minutes
>   Agentless backups every 10 minutes.
>   Powerful deduplication across your host.

**RPO** signifiant : « recovery point objective », mais je n'ai pas besoin de traduire ça avec l’appellation officielle en français, cela doit rester compréhensible.

J'ai cherché **agentless** sur plusieurs sites de traduction, sans autre réponse que « sans agent ».
C'est pour cela que j'aimerais savoir si d'autres personnes ayant déjà eu à traduire ce terme ont trouvé une solution plus satisfaisante.

PS: **Powerful Deduplication across your host** m'intrigue aussi, si jamais quelqu'un a une traduction propre pour ces termes, cela m'intéresserait.

Merci d'avance de toute aide ou piste de recherche.

Comment: Saurais tu expliquer ce que _agentless_ veut dire, et pourquoi "sans agent" n'est pas approprié ?

Comment: @ThomasFrancois si tu comprends l'anglais : http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/agentless , en gros ça veut dire qu'il n'y a pas d'agent à installer sur la machine que l'on doit restaurer. Je n'aime pas trop sans agent parce que "sauvegardes sans agent" n'a pas autant de sens que "agentless backups" je trouve.

Comment: Sauvegarde automatique toutes les 10 minutes sans logiciel supplémentaire (à installer) ?

Comment: Il semble que [**sauvegarde sans agent**](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=sauvegarde+sans+agent&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=#as_qdr=all&q=%22sauvegarde+sans+agent%22) soit un concept en informatique. Ceci dit je ne suis pas informaticien, mais il semble y en avoir beaucoup par ici donc tu auras une réponse circonstanciée certainement.

Comment: @Laure on dit effectivement **sauvegarde sans agent** ou **sauvegarde non liée à un service**

Comment: @Larme Ce n'est pas tout à fait la signification de ce que je cherche, mais merci de la proposition.

Comment: @Biebelaskäse Si on parle d'un système linux basé sur daemon par exemple, on parlera de service, et donc de **sauvegarde sans service attenan**t ou **sauvegarde non liée à un service**, je ne sais pas si c'est la bonne solution néanmoins.

Comment: Non, on ne parle pas d'un système linux basé sur un daemon, il s'agit d'un logiciel pour Microsoft Hyper-V.

Comment: Sur une page du site microsoft, on peut y voir : ["sans agent d'invités en cours d'exécution"](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/magazine/2008.10.disasterr.aspx). On peut donc le raccourcir par "sans agent".

Comment: @SwissFr Merci pour le lien, savez-vous si je peux ajouter votre source dans ma réponse ?

Comment: Oui, sans problème.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- *RPO* : Un *RPO* indique le volume maximal de données que l'on accepte de perdre en cas d'incident majeur entraînant une bascule vers un site de secours. On est ici dans le contexte d'un PRA (Plan de reprise d'activité), en anglais *DRP* (*Disaster recovery plan*). On le traduit en français par **Perte de données maximale admissible** (**PDMA**). Ici les données écrites durant au plus dix minutes avant l'incident pourront être perdues.
- *Agentless* : **Sauvegardes sans agent toutes les dix minutes** sera compris. Il s'agit d'un avantage de la solution de sauvegarde qui est moins intrusive que celle qui consiste à installer un logiciel dédié sur chaque serveur concerné.
- *Powerful Deduplication across your host*. La déduplication est une technique optimisant le volume de données sauvegardées qui consiste à identifier dans le flux de données à sauvegarder, les suites d'octets strictement identiques. Si c'est le cas, ces blocs de données ne seront stockés qu'en un seul exemplaire et les occurrences suivantes référenceront le premier. Ceci peut permettre d'économiser un espace de stockage parfois considérable. En français, on pourra donc dire : **Déduplication performante des données de votre hôte**.

Comment: Merci de votre proposition, je connaissait le sens de deduplication mais le "across" me genait.

Comment: *Across* indique ici que la déduplication n'est pas effectuée par fichier, comme le serait une compression sans perte de données classique, mais est transverse à tous les systèmes de fichier d'un même serveur.

Comment: @SurvenantLazurite Vous pouvez éditer la réponse pour effectuer la correction.

Answer (score 7):

Il semblerait, d'après les réponses en commentaires et après concertation avec une personne dans le domaine que **sans agent** soit bien la traduction usuelle pour **agentless**.

[Source Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/magazine/2008.10.disasterr.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Les sauvegardes se faisant principalement avec des sites répliqués, des miroirs ou des fichiers ZFS sur disques RAID spécialement optimisés, les données sont sécurisées par le système qui utilise un
*Powerful Deduplication across your host* (que l'on devrait pouvoir traduire par *Puissante [déduplication](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9duplication) de tout votre site/système*).

Les données sont réparties dans différentes baies de disques (sur différents site pour les données sensibles), que l'on peut synchroniser (dont on peut reprendre la lecture à partir de l'instant choisi en utilisant les *logs*)

Ce ne sont pas des sauvegardes qui assurent la restauration de données anciennes, mais qui servent pour le redémarrage très rapide des systèmes sinistrés, pour lesquels il faut repartir quelques minutes avant le crash système.

- *Sauvegarde sans agent*

  sera certainement compris par tous, rien n'interdit de préciser comme argument avant-vente :
- c'est une *sauvegarde automatique de redémarrage système intégrée*, sans gestion de service ou de logiciel supplémentaire.

Comment: Attention, la déduplication n'est pas de la réplication, c'est même plutôt le contraire.

Comment: @jlliagre -- En effet, même si elle sous-entend que le système est répliqué, ou sauvegardé en continu, cela ne me semble pas le contraire, mais une forme de 'compression' de l'espace de sauvegarde (nécessaire avec les "zêta volumes" actuels) , car si les données ne sont pas physiquement sur deux aires de stockage physiquement indépendantes, il est plus qu'imprudent de parler de sauvegarde.

Comment: La déduplication n'est pas forcément liée à une opération de sauvegarde ni a la technologie ZFS à laquelle vous faites référence. La sauvegarde avec déduplication recopie toutes les données utiles du serveur source vers le serveur de sauvegarde, les données sont donc bien sur deux aires physiquement indépendantes. Pour se prémunir de l'impact qu'aurait la corruption d'un bloc sauvegardé contenant des  données fortement dupliquées, une ou plusieurs copies de ce bloc peuvent parfois être stockées ailleurs mais on s'éloigne ici des considérations linguistiques...